# After arrival at HK airport, do I need to wait for PCR result where I am tested, before heading to West Kowloon railway station?

Tags: covid-19, hong-kong

After taking PCR (rapid PCR at Prenetics at the airport, or standard or express one at a regular site), do I need to wait there for the result?

Can I take transportation to go to west Kowloon railway station (the station that has high speed train bound to Guangzhou?), in order to catch a train from Guangzhou to some place in time once the result comes out as negative?

I won't have mobile service there. If I can receive the PCR report in SMS or email, does entering the mainland require a PCR report in paper? Do I need to print it out and is there printing service near the station?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

1. You don’t need to wait at the PCR testing site. It’s actually a bad idea staying there, since the site may be crowded.
2. You can of course take public transportation to the high speed railway station. There’s no restriction imposed to inbound tourists. Please also be reminded that MTR (the underground railway system in Hong Kong) doesn’t accept credit cards.
3. You don’t need a physical result in order to enter mainland China. The government site says: “Electronic reports issued by testing institutions or the electronic record downloaded from [www.evt.gov.hk](http://www.evt.gov.hk) can be used for cross-boundary travel. There is no need for persons travelling to the Mainland to collect paper form reports at CTC/CTS.”

Useful links:

- https://enq.evt.gov.hk/evt/web/menu.jsp?
- https://www.communitytest.gov.hk/en/

Comment: "Please also be reminded that MTR (the underground railway system in Hong Kong) doesn’t accept credit cards." - While this is true in general, the Airport Express does take credit cards and this is what the OP may do. I believe it is worth calling out this exception.